# What does comparing of ranges operation returns

Tags: vba, excel, search

I'm trying to code UDF that searches in given text for targets given in an array.

To make things simple I tried to use application functions like `application.find` and `application.match` and `application.iferror` etc.

I stuck with this piece of code:

```
Function SEARCHARRAY(find_items As Range, within_text As Range) As Variant
    Dim search_result As Variant

    search_result = Application.IfError(Application.Find(find_items, within_text), 0) //this should return in application sothing like {0;0;9}, that represent range of items, 0 relate to items not found and 9 i "item found on the 9th position" as regular Find() would return
```

` 
application.find returns an array that on the worksheet looks as {0,0,9}, that represents a range of items, where 0s relate to items not found and 9 is "item found on the 9th position" as regular Find() would return

Later in the code I need to find out how many matched items in this {#,#,#} array are.

But if I use `search_result(i)` it returns nothing.

How can I iterate through the `search_result`?

So far my function works only if only one items matches, that is pretty bad.

The full code goes like this:

```
Function SEARCHARRAY(find_items As Range, within_text As Range) As Variant
Dim search_result, position As Variant

search_result = Application.IfError(Application.Find(find_items, within_text), 0)

If (Application.Sum(search_result) = 0) Then
    matched_item = "no match"
Else
    position = Application.Match(Application.Sum(search_result), search_result, 0)
    matched_item = Application.Index(find_items, position)
End If
SEARCHARRAY = matched_item
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

> But if I use search_result(i) it returns nothing.
>   How can I iterate through the search_result?

`search_result` is a 2D array. To loop through it you can find the upper bound using

```
?UBound(search_result)
```

And then simply loop through it

```
For i = LBound(search_result) To UBound(search_result)
    Debug.Print search_result(i, 1)
Next i
```